# Like button count different with Google Analytic campaign code

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-like

I have Facebook like button installed on my news page.
Now I am getting different like counts for the same page when I have GA campaign code installed, example here:

original URL, 2 likes:
https://www.styo.me/blog/964/

with GA campaign code, 30 likes:

https://www.styo.me/blog/964/?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=FanpageNewsFeed&utm_campaign=FBNewsFeed&utm_term=0908-21&utm_content=news

I assume Facebook is treating these 2 url as 2 separate page, 
how do I consolidate it so it will show unified like count?

Comment: Set the `og:url` Open Graph meta tag, or canonical URL to the main URL for both.

Comment: my current og:url is already set to the main URL, how do I set canonical URL? thanks

Comment: _“my current og:url is already set to the main URL”_ – no it’s not, not for the second URL you mentioned – that has it said to the URL including those tracking parameters. And your `og:image` URL is invalid, too (for both versions) – it needs to be an absolute URL, not a relative one. Use the debug tool, it will show you what Facebook sees. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: okay, I think I know what the problem is, `OG:URL` is using the campaign code url instead of original url.  Thanks a lot!